# Absolutely positioned element with width 100% overflowing relative width parent

Tags: fluid-layout, css

I would like my absolutely positioned element to:

1. be positioned always at the bottom of the container element.
2. span across the whole container element.
3. not span over the padding of the container element.

The container div has a `%` based width.

You can see my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vTuTv/2/

```css
.container {
  min-height: 200px; 
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #3e3e00;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line { 
  background-color: #003e3e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 22px;
  width: 100%;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously if the element wasn't absolutely positioned then I could just use `box-sizing` on the parent element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `width: 100%` for that. The following code does the work.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/vTuTv/4/)

```
.line { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 22px;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;    
}
```

Comment: I want it to not overlap the padding of the container. I could just wrap the whole thing in another div, but wanted to avoid that if there was a better way...

Comment: just a note: `.container` has to be `position: relative;` just like in the question. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull it right over to the left which is not happening at the moment. To do so add:

```
left: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WhK5W/1/